# PDF file download in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

How can we download or view the PDF file using Lightning Component from documents in salesforce1 app, is it possible to do or not, if yes please suggest how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Files or content related object there is a simple event with new lightning namespace which can be used

Here is a sample quick POC

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
   <aura:attribute name="contentId" type="String" default="069B00000015QMwIAM"/>
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Preview Reciept" onclick="{!c.preview }" />
```

Note that the default here is the Id of the content document .

The controller code for same is below

```
({
   preview : function(component, event, helper) {
     $A.get('e.lightning:openFiles').fire({
        recordIds: [component.get("v.contentId")]
    });
   }
})
```

Here is how the component looks in the UI

[image]

Once you click this the below should appear

For SF1 there is a repo which covers the same using a third party JS library

https://github.com/kumarrk21/PDFViewer/tree/master/src/aura

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it is working fine in LE but for SF1 am getting                            "This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: TestLightening8$SalesforceStackExchangeComponents$controller$preview [Cannot read property 'fire' of undefined]"

Comment: i am testing it now in SF1.As per docs it should work in SF1 and community builder as well

Comment: How are you testing it ? Test in on actual device ?

Comment: i tested on  android device, yes as per docs it should work bur not working , i enable and disable locker service also but no luck, for me is major is SF1 app only.

Comment: I updated the answer .You may have to tweak the git code to fit your need but that link does a good job

Comment: @ Mohith Shrivastava:In jspdf I am getting error: jspdf is not defined although it is defined correctly in static resource.