# Lightning download report in pdf

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need to download report in pdf using lightning component.Is there any way to achieve this as I am able to download reports only in csv or xls.Please let me know if this is feasible or if there is any lightning app exchange product.

Comment: I tried by following this approach mentioned in the link:-http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146462/pdf-file-download-in-lightning    I am able to view in pdf but not able to download it in pdf format.

Comment: I used jspdf plugin even but it is throwing error:-"SaveAs is not defined"